# Only shows those lines that contain a keyword or don't

Tags: notepad++, pspad

When you search in pspad, you can click copy and activate "copy lines without matches".

That only copies those lines that contain a keyword or don't to a new window.

How do I accomplish the same in notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `keyword`
- **CHECK** `Bookmark lines`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

You can inverse bookmarks:

- Search menu > Bookmark
- Inverse bookmark

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: How do you copy all lines containing a bookmark/the keyword to a new window?

Comment: @Zurechtweiser: `Search menu >> Bookmark >> Copy Bookmarked lines`